# ORACLE 11g: How to query for the location in external file?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

If I create a table like this in Oracle:

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE emp_load
  2    (employee_number      CHAR(5),
  3     employee_dob         CHAR(20),
  4     employee_last_name   CHAR(20),
  5     employee_first_name  CHAR(15),
  6     employee_middle_name CHAR(15),
  7     employee_hire_date   DATE)
  8  ORGANIZATION EXTERNAL
  9    (TYPE ORACLE_LOADER
 10     DEFAULT DIRECTORY def_dir1
 11     ACCESS PARAMETERS
 12       (RECORDS DELIMITED BY NEWLINE
 13        FIELDS (employee_number      CHAR(2),
 14                employee_dob         CHAR(20),
 15                employee_last_name   CHAR(18),
 16                employee_first_name  CHAR(11),
 17                employee_middle_name CHAR(11),
 18                employee_hire_date   CHAR(10) date_format DATE mask "mm/dd/yyyy"
 19               )
 20       )
 21     LOCATION ('info.dat')
 22    );

 Table created.
```

I need to query and update the file used in the part

```
LOCATION('info.dat')
```

I am trying to get the file name as :

```
select LOCATION from <something>.emp_load;
```

getting error as:

```
Error at line 1
ORA-00904: "LOCATION": invalid identifier
```

**What is the right way to make this query?**

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the operating system path for the file from [the `all_directories` view:](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/server.112/e17110/statviews_1077.htm)

```
select directory_path
from all_directories
where directory_name = 'DEF_DIR1';
```

Your file will be in there.

If you want to find the directory for a table, and other information about it,  you can get that from [the `all_external_tables` view](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/server.112/e17110/statviews_1091.htm).

If you want to find the directory and the location you can get that from [the `all_external_locations` view](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e40402/statviews_1091.htm):

```
select directory_name, location
from all_external_locations
where table_name = 'EMP_LOAD';
```

You may need to specify the owner for any of those queries if you have duplicates in different schemas; or if you own the table then query the `user_*` views instead.

Answer (score 0):

**the way it worked :**

```
select * from all_external_locations where table_name='<table name>' and owner='<owner>';
```